# Spring Cloud Stream custom binder with extension binding properties

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm writing a custom binder for Spring Cloud Streams. The basic binder is hooked into Spring Cloud Streams and is works.

I'm now trying to create extended binding properties. I'm trying to follow the pattern used by the Kalka Binder, but is is a bit of a black hole. Is there documentation or a sample somewhere that shows how to create a binder that supports extension binding properties.

I feel very close. My ConsumerProperty extension is being created and initialized from my application.yml. But them another ConsumerProperty extension is created and never initialized. That is the one that is ultimately passed into my MessageProducer.

Here's my sample-binder: https://github.com/mburbidg/sample-binder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your binder implement the `ExtendedPropertiesBinder` marker interface?

The code that clones the producer properties for such binders is [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/52dad60337fac1fb00146c1d0a11f0ac0903f269/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binding/BindingService.java#L272-L280).

If it does implement it, I would set a breakpoint there to figure out what's going on.

**EDIT**

Two problems:

1. You are creating a new extended binding properties [here](https://github.com/mburbidg/sample-binder/blob/e7373697912a3ade5e2392e8a9974f972cfaeb08/src/main/kotlin/com/adobe/sample/binder/SampleMessageBinder.kt#L15) (the Kafka binder injects the actual properties [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/af5778d157f54520cdeb71cc5c109b58dd33793b/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/config/KafkaBinderConfiguration.java#L121-L122)).
2. Also see KafkaExtendedBindingProperties.getBindings().

Comment: I believe so. I uploaded my sample-binder to github. See link in the original message.

Comment: Yes. See SampleMessageBinder.kt

Comment: Two problems: 1. You are creating a new extended binding properties [here](https://github.com/mburbidg/sample-binder/blob/e7373697912a3ade5e2392e8a9974f972cfaeb08/src/main/kotlin/com/adobe/sample/binder/SampleMessageBinder.kt#L15) (the Kafka binder injects the actual properties [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/af5778d157f54520cdeb71cc5c109b58dd33793b/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/config/KafkaBinderConfiguration.java#L121-L122)). 2. Also see `KafkaExtendedBindingProperties.getBindings()`.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Awesome! Thank you for the help.

I've updated the sample in the github repo, if anyone is interested in a working Spring Cloud Stream sample that supports extended binding configuration.